# Return X number of objects from Cursa.objects.filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been looking for a way to return specific number of object in the json response when I use the 'GET' method.

```
class CursaEsport(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CursaSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        sport = self.kwargs['sport']
        return Cursa.objects.filter(esport=sport, visible=True)
```

If I use this it will return ALL the objects that accomplish the conditions of the filter but I would like to get only 50 objects. I'm not sure that is posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Cursa.objects.filter` returns a `list`, simply limited the number of objects to at most 50 by:

```
Cursa.objects.filter[:50]
```

This is known as splicing

Comment: It works! Thanks! :) I'll mark it as accepted answer asap!